# datatables.js not available to shiny-server apps on AWS

Tags: r, shiny-server

I've followed the directions [Running R on AWS](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3IJSB6BMHWZE5/Running-R-on-AWS) from the AWS Big Data Blog.

When I run an app through Rstudio on port 8787, `datatables.js` is attached and a `renderDataTable()` renders successfully. When I visit the EC2 url serving the app, `datatables.js` is not available and so the `<div>` container holding the datatable remains empty. How do I get `datatables.js` to attach at the EC2 url?

I'm not sure if "attach" is the right wording, but I mean make it available within the app folder without using RStudio to run the app.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `library(DT)` is needed at the top of **ui.R** in addition to being in **server.R**. That fixed the problem.